# How to paste a specific range from one excel sheet to another as Paste Special - Linked Picture using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

I am trying to including a table or specific range from one sheet into another sheet as an image/picture.

In Excel it is done by selecting the entire table from sheet2 and then on sheet1: Paste Special - Linked Picture.

Is there a way to get this done using C#? I am developing a project which requires this task.

Comment: The PasteSpecial method does not have the option of LinkedPicture in C#. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about converting the contents to a picture, but you can read and write to/from a spreadsheet using the Open XML SDK ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)).  I've used it to manipulate Word documents, but I imagine it functions similarly for spreadsheets.